# How to map a column in PySpark DataFrame and avoid getting Null values?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, null, mapping

I have a PySpark DataFrame and I want to map values of a column.

Sample dataset:

```
data = [(1, 'N'), \
        (2, 'N'), \
        (3, 'C'), \
        (4, 'S'), \
        (5, 'North'), \
        (6, 'Central'), \
        (7, 'Central'), \
        (8, 'South')   
  ]
 
columns = ["ID", "City"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)
```

[image]

The mapping dictionary is:

```
{'N': 'North', 'C': 'Central', 'S': 'South'}
```

And I use the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from itertools import chain
mapping_dict = {'N': 'North', 'C': 'Central', 'S': 'South'}
mapping_expr = F.create_map([F.lit(x) for x in chain(*mapping_dict.items())])
df_new = df.withColumn('City_New', mapping_expr[df['City']])
```

And the results are:

[image]

As you can see, I get Null values for rows which I don't include their values in the mapping dictionary. To solve this, I can define mapping dictionary by:

```
{'N': 'North', 'C': 'Central', 'S': 'South', \
 'North': 'North', 'Central': 'Central', 'South': 'South'}
```

However, if there are many unique values in the dataset, it is hard to define a mapping dictionary.

Is there any better way for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a `coalesce`.

here's how it'd look like.

```py
# create separate case whens for each key-value pair
map_whens = [func.when(func.upper('city') == k.upper(), v) for k, v in map_dict.items()]
# [Column<'CASE WHEN (upper(city) = N) THEN North END'>,
#  Column<'CASE WHEN (upper(city) = C) THEN Central END'>,
#  Column<'CASE WHEN (upper(city) = S) THEN South END'>]

# pass case whens to coalesce with last value as `city` field
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('city_new', func.coalesce(*map_whens, 'city')). \
    show()

# +---+-------+--------+
# | id|   city|city_new|
# +---+-------+--------+
# |  1|      N|   North|
# |  2|      N|   North|
# |  3|      C| Central|
# |  4|      S|   South|
# |  5|  North|   North|
# |  6|Central| Central|
# |  7|Central| Central|
# |  8|  South|   South|
# +---+-------+--------+
```

Comment: you could also just do `coalesce(mapping_expr[df['City']], 'city')`